# How to spot restricted and unrestricted GARCH models and identify the number of restrictions

Tags: garch, degrees-of-freedom

Between GARCH(4,1) and GARCH(3,4), what will be the number of restrictions, and which model will be restricted and unrestricted?

Comment: Could you explain the "spot ... models" from your question title? It does not seem related to the content of the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two models are not nested within each other, so you cannot say that one is a restricted version of the other.

You could consider GARCH(4,4) as a model that nests both. Then GARCH(4,1) would have 3 restrictions and GARCH(3,4) would have 1 restriction with respect to GARCH(4,4).

Comment: Also, can we have GARCH(1,1) having 2 restrictions with respect to GARCH(2,2)?

Comment: @SaadUllahKhan, sure, we can.